# MacLane's Homology Book exercise doubt

Tags: homological-algebra, group-extensions

I have been reading MacLane's book on Homological Algebra, and in chapter 3 section 2 exercise 1 , he asks to do the following

> For abelian groups, show that a normalized function on $C \times C$ to $A$ is a factor system for extension of abelian groups if and only if it satisfies the identities
>
> $f(c,d)+f(c+d,e)=f(c,d+e)+f(d,e)$, $f(c,d)=f(d,c)$
>
> Where normalized functions satisfies $f(c,0)=0=g(0,d)$, $g(r,0)=0$.

I think i was able to do this $\rightarrow$, but the other one i have  a doubt that well i have these functions with these properties , am i supposed from this properties choose representative functions $u$ for elements on $C$, and show that $(f,g)$ are a factor system for this representative function $u$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there also a condition relating $f$ and $g$?

Comment: I think all there is i already mentioned it

Comment: Oh yes, I guess the cross-conditions only start to show up starting from abelian 3-cocycles, not for 2-cocycles. My bad, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the function $g$ is basically useless here, since it is supposed to encode the action of the base ring $R$ for $R$-modules, but for abelian groups the action of $R=\mathbb{Z}$ is already given by the group structure.

So as you guessed if you have such a symmetric $2$-cocycle $f:C\times C\to A$, what you want to do is define an abelian group $G$ with an exact sequence $0\to A\to G\to C\to 0$ and a set-theoretic normalized section $u:C\to G$ such that $f$ is the factor system.

It is very easy, you basically don't have any choice if you think about how factor sets are defined: take
$$G = A\times C$$
with the product
$$(x,c)\star (y,d)=(x+y+f(c,d),c+d).$$

Then $A\to G$ is just $a\mapsto (a,0)$, $G\to C$ is $(x,c)\mapsto c$, and the section $u:C\to G$ is $u(c)=(0,c)$.

You can check that your first identity reflects associativity, and the second one commutativity of $\star$.

Comment: I mean sure once you see the construction its easy to verify thats its going to be what we want, i just wasnt sure quite how to get there, but Thanks !